# Messaging system for moderators

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I just wanted to ask, why there does not exist any personal messaging system in this site, just to be able to contact users? At least, moderators should have this ability to contact users personally in case they want to note them something.

[As an instance](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/25664/from-which-level-of-education-is-it-better-to-choose-teacher-assistants?noredirect=1#comment53243_25664), somebody wanted to inform me that it is better to change my way I am doing tag edits. Because moderators can not send personal messages to the users, he/she had to comment under one of my questions. His attitude to help me to learn something about tag edits was great (I am so thankful to this attitude), but the way he informed me, brought my energy and courage to participate in the site, down.

Comment: Note: the referenced comments were removed, since they were not relevant to the question they were posted on.

Comment: I noticed and thank you so much not because of removing the comments, but because you helped me understand the site better than before.

Comment: This is by design: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Answer (score 3):

Moderators *do* have the ability to send messages to users. It's usually done only in exceptional situations.

For typical situations, commenting is the correct way to contact a user. Alternatively, there is chat.

There is also some less explicit feedback. For example, if you often raise flags, you should go back and look how many were marked "helpful" and how many "declined." A high ratio of declined flags is a signal that you should ask for help (on meta) understanding the flagging system. Similarly, you can watch your suggested edits, and if they are declined, you should take that as feedback.

Comment: Even under a non-relevant question?!

Comment: @Parsa you can directly contact other users about their activity on this site by commenting near the relevant activity. For anything else, there's [chat]

Comment: @Parsa in case someone writes a comment in a place where it isn't relevant, it should be flagged for removal

Comment: As you mentioned, putting comment on **relevant activity**, not any question of the user. I also believe that Academia Chat is the best way to note users about their misunderstandings.